# Convertir FileInputStream a array?

Tags: java, json

Como puedo convertir un `java.io.FileInputStream` a un array?

Estos guardo en el cache del app un archivo json y luego lo trato de acceder pero me sale que es un aricho `fileInputStream`?

aqui esta el codigo que estoy usando para el cache

```
private void cacheFile(JSONObject response) {
     JSONObject res  = response;
     String filename = "jsonfile";
     FileOutputStream outputStream;

     try {
         outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         outputStream.write(res.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
         outputStream.close();
         Log.e(TAG, "Bien");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

private void readCache(String filename) {
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
        inputStream.read();
        inputStream.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es un aricho? `inputStream.read();` significa que solo leiste un byte y nunca lo usaste?

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar de un InputStream a un array pudieras usar un java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream que es una clase con la que puedes escribir y acumular bytes.

Te pongo ejemplo:

Vamos a crear un buffer para extraer info del archivo:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1000]; //el tamaño es a criterio tuyo; yo no lo haría muy
                                 // grande porque de todas formas vas a escribir a
                                 // otro array

 ByteArrayOutputStream salida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 inputStream = openFileInput(filename);

 int leidos = inputStream.read(buffer);

 while (leidos > 0) {
     salida.write(buffer, 0, leidos);
     leidos = inputStream.read(buffer);
 }

 salida.flush();
```

Hasta aquí ya leímos todo lo que tenía el archivo via su InputStream y lo escribimos en la salida. Ahora para obtener el arreglo usamos un método:

```
byte[] arreglo = salida.toByteArray();
```

Ya tienes el arreglo, o array.

Te paso la liga de esta clase:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html